# Add aggregation from different dataframe as column

Tags: python, azure, azure-databricks, pyspark

With this dataset:

```
start,end,rms,state,maxTemp,minTemp
2019-02-20T16:16:31.752Z,2019-02-20T17:33:34.750Z,4.588481,charge,35.0,32.0
2019-02-20T17:33:34.935Z,2019-02-20T18:34:49.737Z,5.770562,discharge,35.0,33.0
```

And this:

```
[{"EventDate":"2019-02-02T16:17:00.579Z","Value":"23"},
{"EventDate":"2019-02-02T16:18:01.579Z","Value":"23"},
{"EventDate":"2019-02-02T16:19:02.581Z","Value":"23"},
{"EventDate":"2019-02-02T16:20:03.679Z","Value":"23"},
{"EventDate":"2019-02-02T16:21:04.684Z","Value":"23"},
{"EventDate":"2019-02-02T17:40:05.693Z","Value":"23"},
{"EventDate":"2019-02-02T17:40:06.694Z","Value":"23"},
{"EventDate":"2019-02-02T17:40:07.698Z","Value":"23"},
{"EventDate":"2019-02-02T17:40:08.835Z","Value":"23"}]

schema = StructType([
    StructField('EventDate', TimestampType(), True),
    StructField('Value', FloatType(), True)
])
```

I want to add max and min values of the json dataset as columns into the csv dataset.

I have tried:

```
cyclesWithValues = csvDf\
.withColumn("max", jsondata.filter((col("EventDate") >= csvDf.start) & (col("EventDate") <= csvDf.end)).agg({"value": "max"}).head()["max(Value)"])\
.withColumn("min", jsondata.filter((col("EventDate") >= csvDf.start) & (col("EventDate") <= csvDf.end)).agg({"value": "min"}).head()["min(Value)"])
```

But I get this error:

```
AnalysisException: 'Resolved attribute(s) start#38271,end#38272 missing from EventDate#38283,Value#38286 in operator !Filter ((EventDate#38283 >= start#38271) && (EventDate#38283 <= end#38272)).;;\n!Filter ((EventDate#38283 >= start#38271) && (EventDate#38283 <= end#38272))\n+- Project [EventDate#38283, cast(Value#38280 as float) AS Value#38286]\n   +- Project [to_timestamp(EventDate#38279, None) AS EventDate#38283, Value#38280]\n      +- Relation[EventDate#38279,Value#38280] json\n'
```

I have a solution based on arrays, but it seems very slow, so I was hoping something like this would speed things up a bit.

Right now I am using this solution:

```
dfTemperature = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("path")
dfTemperatureCast = dfTemperature.withColumn("EventDate", to_timestamp(dfTemperature.EventDate)).withColumn("Value", dfTemperature.Value.cast('float'))

def AddVAluesToDf(row):
  temperatures = dfTemperatureCast.filter((col("EventDate") >= row["start"]) & (col("EventDate") <= row["end"]))
  maxTemp = temperatures.agg({"value": "max"}).head()["max(value)"]
  minTemp = temperatures.agg({"value": "min"}).head()["min(value)"]
  return (row.start, row.end, row.rms, row.state, maxTemp, minTemp)

pool = ThreadPool(10)
withValues = pool.map(AddVAluesToDf, rmsDf)

schema = StructType([
    StructField('start', TimestampType(), True),
    StructField('end', TimestampType(), True),
    StructField('maxTemp', FloatType(), True),
    StructField('minTemp', FloatType(), True)
])

cyclesDF = spark.createDataFrame(withValues, schema)
```

Comment: how big is your second dataframe?

Comment: second dataset can be around 100k rows, depending on reporting period. First dataset is not necessarily very large. Less than 200 rows.

Comment: Is this your working solution? The one you have posted above

Comment: Yes, this works, but as you see it creates an array, then creates a dataframe from that array. I would much rather have something that works solely in the dataframe world without arrays

Comment: can you also share schema of your second dataset?

Comment: It is baiscally datetime, float. I added schema definiton below dataset